# Scrape the salary from indeed.com

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape salary from indeed.com using beautiful soup.

The salary is given as:

```html
<div id="vjs-jobinfo">
        <div id="vjs-jobtitle">Senior Data Scientist/ Machine learning engineer</div>
        <div>
            <span id="vjs-cn">Intellify</span>
            <span id="vjs-loc"> - Sydney NSW</span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <span>$120,000 - $160,000 a year</span>
            &nbsp;-&nbsp;
            <span>Full-time,&nbsp;Part-time</span>
        </div>
</div>
```

My solution:

```
new_soup = BeautifulSoup(new_html, 'html.parser', from_encoding='utf-8')

for titles in new_soup.find_all('div',{'id':'vjs-jobtitle'}):
    print(titles.text)

print('\n')

for company_name in new_soup.find_all('span',{'id':'vjs-cn'}):
    print(company_name.text)

print('\n')

for company_location in new_soup.find_all('span',{'id':'vjs-loc'}):
    print(company_location.text)
```

But I can't get the salary as I have span has no attribute there. Can anyone help please.

Comment: What have you tried? We can’t help you without that!

Comment: I added my solution. its just that I am not able to figure out a way in beautiful soup to extract values without attributes as if i just use span, i will get multiple results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is since you know that the salary is in the 3rd `span` tag, you can directly access it

```
all_span=new_soup.find_all("span")
salary=all_span[2].getText()
#$120,000 - $160,000 a year
```

**EDIT** : Since you know salary must start with a dollar symbol, you can also use regex to find it

```
salary=new_soup.find('span', text=re.compile(r'^\$')).getText()
#$120,000 - $160,000 a year
```

Comment: I wish!! Unfortunately, I have not trimmed it down but I am scraping the whole page instead.

Comment: @Kris Check if the updated answer works?

Answer (score 2):

You can use CSS-style selectors like:

```
new_soup.select_one("div#vjs-jobinfo div:nth-of-type(3)").findChild().text
```